# `assign` function and strings

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["A1", "A2"], "B" : [1, 2]}
```

and list of strings: `l = ["C", "D"]`. I would like to add two columns to `df` as follows using `assign` function:

```
df = df.assign(l[0] = df["A"])
```

but I got an error "Keyword can't be an expression". What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a dict because `l[0]` is not a valid variable name:

```
df = df.assign(**{l[0]: df['A']})
print(df)

# Output
    A  B   C
0  A1  1  A1
1  A2  2  A2
```

Comment: @Degeleqgo. (about your previously removed comment) Do you mean you already have a "C" and "D" column?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Is this what you want?

```
df[l[0]] = df["A"]
df[l[1]] = df["A"]
```